# Spark comparing boolean column with string column works differently to comparing int and string where values are equal

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe containing `boolean`, `int` and `double` values as well as `string` columns that have the same values as these but in a `String` format. When I add a column to check if they are equal, it works for ints and doubles but not for `booleans` and I can't understand why.

Why does Spark treat equality with `boolean` columns differently and how can I get around this to achieve the same behaviour of other types (ideally avoiding any casting)?

Example below

Let's say I have a case class:

```
case class TestData(bool: Boolean, int: Int, dbl: Double, bool_string: String, int_string: String, dbl_string: String)
```

I create a collection of this and create a dataframe:

```
val df = Seq(TestData(true, 1, 1.01, "true", "1", "1.01"), TestData(false, 2, 2.02, "false", "2", "2.02")).toDF
```

Then add a column to check whether booleans are equal to their string value counterparts:

```
val boolEq = df.withColumn("bool_eq", col("bool") === col("bool_string"))
```

Add a column to check whether the ints are equal to their string value counterparts:

```
val intEq = boolEq.withColumn("int_eq", col("int") === col("int_string"))
```

Finally, when I do a show on the final dataframe the output looks like:

```
intEq.show
+-----+---+----+-----------+----------+----------+-------+------+
| bool|int| dbl|bool_string|int_string|dbl_string|bool_eq|int_eq|
+-----+---+----+-----------+----------+----------+-------+------+
| true|  1|1.01|       true|         1|      1.01|   null|  true|
|false|  2|2.02|      false|         2|      2.02|   null|  true|
+-----+---+----+-----------+----------+----------+-------+------+
```

How can I get around this so that booleans work in the same way as ints and other types?

EDIT:
This is with Spark version 1.6.0

Comment: Only casting is working! `val boolEq = df.withColumn("bool_eq", col("bool").cast("string") === col("bool_string"))`

Answer (score 2):

Which version of spark are you using?

Is working fine for me with spark-shell version version 2.3.1

side note: I had to change the column name from int to int_original because it was a reserved word

**case class**

```
case class TestData(bool: Boolean, int_original: Int, dbl: Double, bool_string: String, int_string: String, dbl_string: String)
```

**input**

```
df.show
+-----+------------+----+-----------+----------+----------+
| bool|int_original| dbl|bool_string|int_string|dbl_string|
+-----+------------+----+-----------+----------+----------+
| true|           1|1.01|       true|         1|      1.01|
|false|           2|2.02|      false|         2|      2.02|
+-----+------------+----+-----------+----------+----------+


df.printSchema
root
 |-- bool: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- int_original: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- dbl: double (nullable = false)
 |-- bool_string: string (nullable = true)
 |-- int_string: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dbl_string: string (nullable = true)
```

**output**

```
import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col


df.withColumn("bool_eq", col("bool") === col("bool_string")).withColumn("int_eq", col("int_original") === col("int_string")).show


+-----+------------+----+-----------+----------+----------+-------+------+
| bool|int_original| dbl|bool_string|int_string|dbl_string|bool_eq|int_eq|
+-----+------------+----+-----------+----------+----------+-------+------+
| true|           1|1.01|       true|         1|      1.01|   true|  true|
|false|           2|2.02|      false|         2|      2.02|   true|  true|
+-----+------------+----+-----------+----------+----------+-------+------+
```

Comment: hey I'm using 1.6.0 have added it to my post as well for reference. Looks like this may be a versioning issue. Any ideas to get around it with my current version?

Comment: try importing import scala.language.implicitConversions

Comment: Then you may need to explicitly cast it to String